# Shiny Interactive Table with Manual Input and Summary Table Output

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a Shiny app that I'm working on where I'd like to give the end user the ability to specify a value and then have a calculation take place under the hood and the results produced in a summary table.

So far, I've been able to create the dashboard for selection and a summary table based on those selections.

The example below is a group of restaurants that an ownership group holds. There is a daily net for each restaurant. The UI allows the owner to choose multiple restaurants, which populate one table, and have a second summary table aggregate the daily net.

What I'd like is for there to be a second input for each restaurant where the owner can manually specify the number of hours that they would like to have each restaurant opened for and in the summary table get the sum of `daily_net` / `hours_opened` so they can have a way of forecasting their total income based on their decisions of how long to keep certain restaurants open over others.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

## data
Restaurant <- c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5")
daily_net <- c(250000, 90000, 165000, 113000, 340000)
df <- data.frame(Restaurant, daily_net)
df

## UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Total Income"),

        selectizeInput(
            inputId = "Restaurant",
            label = "Restaurant",
            choices = Restaurant,
            selected = "",
            multiple = T
            ),

        mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "r_table"),
    tableOutput(outputId = "summary_table"))

)

## Server
server <- function(input, output){

    dat <- reactive({
                        dataset1 <- df %>% filter(Restaurant %in% input$Restaurant)
                        dataset1
                })

    dat2 <- reactive({
            dataset2 <- dat() %>%
                      summarize(total_net = sum(daily_net))
            dataset2
    })  


    output$r_table <- renderTable(dat(), align = "l")
    output$summary_table <- renderTable(dat2(), align = "l")

}


## Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a decent enough work around for what I was trying to get to.

I just create several numeric inputs in the UI and then structure them in the reactive component of the server to do the math and produce the result.

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

Restaurant <- c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5")
daily_net <- c(250000, 90000, 165000, 113000, 340000)
df <- data.frame(Restaurant, daily_net)
df

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Total Income"),

        selectizeInput(
            inputId = "Restaurant",
            label = "Restaurant",
            choices = Restaurant,
            selected = "",
            multiple = T
            ),

    numericInput("h1", "Hour - Restaurant 1", 1),
    numericInput("h2", "Hour - Restaurant 2", NA),
    numericInput("h3", "Hour - Restaurant 3", NA),
    numericInput("h4", "Hour - Restaurant 4", NA),

        mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "r_table"),
    tableOutput(outputId = "summary_table"))

)

server <- function(input, output){



    dat <- reactive({

           Hours <- c(input$h1, input$h2, input$h3, input$h4)
           Hours <- Hours[!is.na(Hours)]

                        dataset1 <- df %>% filter(Restaurant %in% input$Restaurant) %>%
                                      mutate(Number = seq_along(Restaurant),
                                                Hours = Hours,
                                                net_per_hour = daily_net  / Hours) %>%
                                      select(Number, Restaurant, daily_net, Hours, net_per_hour)
                        dataset1
                })

    dat2 <- reactive({
            dataset2 <- dat() %>%
                      summarize(total_per_hour = sum(net_per_hour))
            dataset2
    })  


    output$r_table <- renderTable(dat(), align = "l")
    output$summary_table <- renderTable(dat2(), align = "l")

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```